# what is the reason of "Trying to return an unknown connection2! " warning message

Tags: java, jpa, jboss

I have a question;
My eclipse is last Kepler Release. I use JBOSS EAP 6.1, and JPA.

I have save methods as;

```
saveTicket(template, ticketContent);

saveValidation(resultCode, template, transactionId, stationName, gateId, side, barcode);
```

I use Soap UI and I send an xml file to test if the system is working or not.
If I close this methods(`saveTicket()`, `saveValidation()`) I do not get any errors or warnings. However, if I use these methods I get warning message as following:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Trying to return an unknown connection2! org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedConnectionJDK6

Actually this warning message does not affect the system, after sending xml file database updated correctly and save methods working but
I wonder why I get this warning message.

Is there anybody who encountered this error before?

Comment: Don't you have any idea about this issue?

Comment: This answer <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785798/what-is-the-cause-of-this-error-java-lang-illegalstateexception-trying-to-retur> details the cause very succinctly. Might be of use to others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable cached connection manager, for that you have to put the property use-ccm ="false" in your datasorce, this must be done directly in the stanalone.xml.

Cached connection manager

Used for debugging connections and supporting lazy enlistment of a connection in a
transaction, tracking whether they are used and released properly by the application.
The following table describes the attributes you can set for the cached connection manager.

Probably you have connections to the database that are not being used correctly for Jboss.